# MySQL replication - How to verify replicated data?

Tags: mysql, replication, verify

How is it possible to verify the replicated data on the slave MySQL server?

Any recommendable tools for the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running on *nix there is "Percona Toolkit"

You may check out : [Percona Toolkit](http://www.percona.com/software/percona-toolkit/)

There is also "[Maatkit](http://www.maatkit.org/)" but it moved to Percona I see.

Answer (score 0):

Exact tool could do this job is [pt-table-checksum](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-table-checksum.html) which performs an online replication consistency check by executing checksum queries on the master, which produces different results on replicas that are inconsistent with the master. The optional DSN specifies the master host. The tool’s exit status is nonzero if any differences are found, or if any warnings or errors occur.